# It is possible to test view below a progress dialog, using espresso?

Tags: android, unit-testing, automated-tests, android-espresso

I am trying use a function to check consistency of the activity graphic elements at any time. I found out that when the progressdialog is showing the espresso can't find any view bellow. Is there any way get the view bellow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you use a [RootMatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/RootMatchers.html). For example:

```
// Specifically target the main window view hierarchy
onView(withId(R.id.view_to_match))
    .inRoot(withDecorView(is(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView())))
    .perform(click());
```

Or maybe:

```
// Specifically disregard the dialog window view hierarchy
onView(withId(R.id.view_to_match))
    .inRoot(not(isDialog()))
    .perform(click());
```

See [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/recipes.html#targeting-non-default-windows) for an example.

Hope that helps!

Comment: almost work. i got this error. "Waited for the root of the view hierarchy to have window focus and not request layout for 10 seconds. If you specified a non default root matcher, it may be picking a root that never takes focus. Root:".

Comment: What API are you running against? I recall progress dialog animations on 21+ causing Espresso to hang, so that could be factor.

Comment: 25 and 26. I disable the animations.

Comment: my script didn't disable on of the settings. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
onView(withText("Request Number")).inRoot(not(isDialog())).perform(click());
```

Worked for me!

Request Number is a 'text' on 'Button'